# Javascript square bracket notation couldn't be evaluated properly while using an android webview. Any advice to fix it?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I'm using android webview and want to make dynamic function calls over the Javascript Interface.  My interface's name is **AndroidBridge**. And here is my code:

```
AndroidBridge[key](values[key]);
```

It works properly on the browser. But when it comes to my webview, is throwing the error below:

```
Error connecting controller TypeError: AndroidBridge[key] is not a function [object Object]"
```

Any advice to jump over that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you the two possible reasons for that issue now:

1. Missing `@JavascriptInterface` annotation.
2. The method is missing or params not matching.

I don't know why browser's js interpreter looks to "a square named version of that object", but method names that match should work without that errors.

I can leave here a fully working example:

```
class JsBridge {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(message: String) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "JsBridge showToast message:$message")
        val currentActivity = current ?: return
        Toast.makeText(currentActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val instance: JsBridge = JsBridge()
    }
}

// Somewhere in your code
webView.addJavascriptInterface(JsBridge.instance, "AndroidBridge")
```

Now you can call that method in the js side:

```
AndroidBridge.showToast('A message');
// or
AndroidBridge['showToast']('A message');
```

They both should work.